# Why is a memory round-trip faster than not performing the round-trip?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

I've got some simple 32bit code which computes the product of an array of 32bit integers. The inner loop looks like this:

```
@@loop:
mov esi,[ebx]
mov [esp],esi
imul eax,[esp]
add ebx, 4
dec edx
jnz @@loop
```

What I'm trying to understand is why the above code is 6% faster than these two versions of the code, which does not perform the redundant memory round-trip:

```
@@loop:
mov esi,[ebx]
imul eax,esi
add ebx, 4
dec edx
jnz @@loop
```

and

```
@@loop:
imul eax,[ebx]
add ebx, 4
dec edx
jnz @@loop
```

The two latter pieces of code execute in virtually the same time, and as mentioned both are 6% slower than the first piece (165ms vs 155ms, 200 million elements).

I've tried manually aligning the jump target to a 16 byte boundary, but it makes no difference.

I'm running this on an Intel i7 4770k, Windows 10 x64.

Note: I know the code could be improved by doing all sorts of optimizations, however I'm only interested in the performance difference between the above pieces of code.

Comment: I can't give you references (because they probably don't exist, since they'd reveal trade secrets), but you are probably seeing an artifact of the extraordinary effort that Intel puts into L1 cache performance.

Comment: Does this still occur when you insert a dummy load `mov ecx, [ebx]` in the second version?

Comment: How's the performance in the cached case?  The first loop should issue out of the loop buffer at one per 2 cycles (since it's 5 fused-domain uops on your Haswell CPU).  The other two can issue at one cycle per iteration.  However, the loop-carried `imul` dependency chain should limit them all to 3 cycles per iteration.  The first doesn't have the store and reload in the critical path dependency chain, and Haswell can execute 2x load + 1x store every cycle.  (Pre-Haswell didn't have a dedicated store AGU).  I can't see why it's faster, but it makes sense that it's not slower.

Comment: I think even with your input data set fitting in L1, the first loop wouldn't be slower.  The latency of a store and reload is probably a bit longer than 3c (but not a lot, thanks to store-forwarding.  Agner Fog has it at 5c).  It's not part of the loop-carried dep chain, and the operations are pipelined, so the load/store/load for an iteration can be done by the time the Re-Order-Buffer is ready to execute the `imul`.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Unfortunately I had to restore to Win8.1, it will take me a day to recreate this project to provide the requested information.

Comment: In my opinion we should take in to acount that we are running inside an Operating System. Since the loop takes quite long, there are chances that the thread is scheduled out many times (and it could also change CPU too!). The scheduler can affect this kind of measures significantly. I.e. the first version of the program involves the stack, but the other two don't. In the latter case the OS could decide to page out temporarily the stack memory, and it takes some aditional time to reload it when needed. In my experience it is easy to be confused by "performace artifacts" due to modern OSs.

Comment: @harold Adding a dummy _load_ did not help, but adding a dummy _store_ did! If I make the code look like `mov esi, [ebx]; mov [esp], esi; imul eax, esi` I get the same performance as the original. Note the store to `[esp]` is entirely redundant.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini I'm fairly sure this does not matter. The timings I reported vary with +/- 1ms at most between multiple runs (ie 154-156ms vs 164-166ms). This is across reboots as well. In addition I have 24 GByte of free memory, so I don't see why the OS should be paging out anything.

Comment: @Asbjørn does it make a difference which register you store in the dummy?

Comment: @harold No, not that I could figure out. I need to store to memory, but how and where to seems not to matter. Even storing at a fixed global variable gets the same performance increase, ie `mov [0x004e03d8], esi`. Doing a dummy store to another register does not help. I must admit this is really confusing me. I'll try to replicate this in another compiler, just as a sanity check.

Comment: @Asbjørn: Can you check the binary code generated? I don't really think we can find somethging weird in this case, but I am vaguely remembering that a very old version os gas (but you are not using it...) incorrectly "collapsed" the "imul eax,r/m32" (0F AF r/m32) case into "imul r/m32" (F7 r/m32), which also corrupted EDX! Unlikely, but since we are investigating...

Comment: @Asbjørn (cont.) A different way to check it is by using a different register instead of EAX.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini When debugging, the binary code matches my asm. I tested the "imul r/m32" variant just for fun, it's slower, but it does show the same pattern with regards to the dummy store: without store 230ms, with store 220ms. I'll try avoiding EAX as well.

Comment: @Asbjørn I've just tried to repeat your experiment, but at the moment I can use only a Core2 Quad Q9000 @ 2MHz, and Ubuntu 14.04 x64 as OS. A very different environment :-( . And the result is in effect less confusing than yours: 344 ms with "imul [esp]", 288 with "imul reg.". So the behaviour you are observing seems to be something specific of core i7 or W10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect but can't be sure that you are preventing a stall on a data dependency:

The code looks like this:

```
@@loop:
    mov esi,[ebx]    # (1)Load the memory location to esi reg
    (mov [esp],esi)  # (1)optionally store the location on the stack      
    imul eax,[esp]   # (3) Perform the multiplication
    add ebx, 4       # (1) Add 4
    dec edx          # (1)decrement counter
    jnz @@loop       # (0**) loop
```

Those numbers in brackets are the latencies of the instructions ... that jump is 0 if the branch predictor guesses correctly (which since it will mostly loop it will most of the time).

So: while the multiplication is still going (3 instructions) we get back to the top of the loop after 2 and try to load in to the memory and has to stall.  Or we could do a store ... which we can do at the same time as our multiplication and then not stall at all.

What about the dummy store you ask?  Why does that work?  Notice you are storing the critical value that we are using to multiply to memory.  Thus the processor can use this value which is being stored in memory and clobber the register.

So why can't the processor do this anyway?  The processor can't produce more memory accesses than you ask it to or it could interfere with multi-processor programs (imagine that cache line that you are writing to is shared and you have to invalidate it on other CPUs every loop by writing to it ... ouch!).

All of this is pure speculation, but it seems to match all the evidence (your code and my knowledge of the intel architecture ... and x86 assembly).  Hopefully someone can point out if I have something wrong.